# How to configure alerting in Grafana to send an alert if there is no new data after e.g. 30 minutes?

Tags: grafana, grafana-alerts

Is it possible to configure [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to send an alert if there is no new data for a query for e.g. 30 minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an alert as following:

> **Rule** Name: NoData, Evaluate every: 1m, For: 30m
>
> **Condition** When: last() of: query(A,10m,now) has no value

Comment: Just another question: Can i add two alerts to one visualization.

Comment: Yes, if you cannot figure it out, *post* a new question about that.

Comment: so it means that evaluation is done 30 times and decision is taken from the last 10m window if no value is found send an alert?

if my assumption is true then there could be a case where there is data that exists later last 10 min window